# Remove margin space from QDockWidget in QMainWindow

Tags: qt, qmainwindow

`QDockWidget` is giving  left margin of `4px` to the widget i add to the `dockwidget`. I tried

```
theToolbarDock->setStyleSheet("margin: 0px; border:0px");
theToolbarDock->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
```

and

> theToolbarDock->layout()->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

But in vain. It still persist with `4px` left margin i have to remove from the `QDockWidget`. the dock widget is in `RightDockWidgetArea`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
QMainWindow::separator {
    width: 10px;
    height: 0px;
    margin: -10px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Let me know if it's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

setContentsMargins is applicable to the layout only..  not the widget.

Try setting it on the layout your dockwidget instead.